# Flash[:warning] not working with redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

I am using flash[:notice] to display success messages and flash[:warning] to display warning and error messages.

Flash[:notice] is working fine even while redirecting to another page, but flash[:warning] does not work with redirection.

when I check in my view file flash[:warning] is passed as nil.

how to use flash[:warning] with redirect_to ?

Comment: use flash[:error] for warnings/errors

Comment: Problem is I use flash[:notice] to show up flash messges in green color and flash[:error] to show up flash messages in red color and flash[:warning] to show flash messages in orange color. My flash[:notice] and flash[:error] works fine but not my flash[:warning].

Comment: have you wrote up <%= flash[:warning] %> in specific view?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass flashes through redirects using

```
redirect_to 'page/to/redirect/to', :flash => { :error => 'Some error' }
```

Comment: Problem is I use flash[:notice] to show up flash messges in green color and flash[:error] to show up flash messages in red color and flash[:warning] to show flash messages in orange color. My flash[:notice] and flash[:error] works fine but not my flash[:warning].

Comment: hm, and passing `:flash => { :warning => "some warning" }` doesn't work you say?

Comment: @user001 you probably having additional redirect between your startpoint-endpoint or you're reassigning flash at some point. Anyways - problem lies in your code and not in some voodoo magic about flash.

Comment: Yes I have multiple redirects so how can I make my flash[:warning] work with multiple redirects?